# How can we create object in desire database in rest framework

Tags: python, django, database, api, django-rest-framework

I'm creating project but that project is saving in the default database. I want to create that project in other database... I'm using CreatApiView..

```
class CreateProjectAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """This endpoint allows for creation of a Project"""
    queryset = Project.objects.using('notification_dev').all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProjectSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()
        draft_request_data = self.request.data.copy()
        print("draft_request_data :",draft_request_data)
        kwargs["data"] = draft_request_data
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't get it how can i use that `.using("otherdataName")` in `get_serializer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can not (or you shouldn't) be performing database operations in `get_serializer`.

The execution flow goes like this:

`view.create --> serializer.save --> serializer.create --> model.save`

So, editing the model.save function is the preferred option. The only downside to that is during `bulk_create` but you aren't using that.

Look at the following code from Django documentation:

```py
Model.save(force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, update_fields=None)¶
```

So, updating `using` there will be efficient.